# Not able to access header param in Spring Integration (DSL)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I do have a method which returns MessageHandler. The signature of the method is mentioned below

```
public MessageHandler sendToDestination(URI uri,String resource,String query);
```

I am calling sendToDestination method in one of my flows. sendToDestination takes query as one of the parameter. This parameter is obtained from the header. Pseudo code of the same is pasted below

```
flow -> flow
        .handle((payload, headers) -> { 
String queryParam = headers.get(QUERY_STRING, String.class);
msgHandler = httpGateway.sendToDestination (uri, resource, queryParam); 
return msgHandler; 
})
.handle(someOtherOperation)
```

However I am having trouble in handling the msgHandler that is returned (I even tried returning queryParam, but I am unsure of how we can handle the value returned in the next step in the flow)
Before the control goes to .handle(someOtherOperation), I want the value returned to be handled by
assigning to variable (static variables didn't retain values), so that I can use it in function calls or if in case msgHandler is returned, I want it to be handled before the call goes to
.handle(someOtherOperation).
Any suggestions would help.

Answer (score 0):

You see you have `return msgHandler;` in the `handle()` function. According the service activator pattern whatever is returned from the method call becomes a `payload` for the messages to produce from this endpoint . So in your case a payload is that `MessageHandler`. When technically it is OK to have `MH` in the payload, I guess this not what you are expecting. You probably want to have that `MH` evaluated or your logic and vision for the flow should be revised. Please, share with us a business purpose of your gateway and its result.

Comment: Basically I am setting queryParam as a header and I have to extract it and send it as an argument to 
**`public MessageHandler sendToDestination(URI uri,String resource,String query);`**
Later the response received from the endpoint is transformed from json to xml and sent to the client.

Comment: I tried 2 approaches
1) I am extracting queryParam in handle method of the flow and send it to sendToDestination method which basically returns a MH. This MH should be evaluated before the response is transformed to xml. Pseudo code for the same mentioned below

Comment: `flow -> flow
        .handle((payload, headers) -> { 
String queryParam = headers.get(QUERY_STRING, String.class);
msgHandler = httpGateway.sendToDestination (uri, resource, queryParam); 
return msgHandler;  
})
// MessageHandler should be evaluated over here before it goes to next Step.
.handle(responseReceived)
.transform(JSON_TO_XML)`

Comment: 2) I extracted queryParam and later returned the same. Pseudo code for the same mentioned below
`flow -> flow
  .handle((payload, headers) -> { 
  String queryParam = headers.get(QUERY_STRING, String.class);
  return queryParam; //Tried even static variable over here but didn't work
})  
// Query param returend should be set to variable so that the variable can be passed as paramater to sendToDestination method.
.handle(httpGateway.sendToDestination (uri, resource, queryParam))
.handle(responseReceived)
.transform(JSON_TO_XML)`

Comment: Right. The question is: why does your `sendToDestination()` return `MH`, but not a result of service call? your current code will just set that `MH` into a reply message payload.